# Getting 'Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error)' during Email Sign-In with Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on implementing email sign-in functionality in my web application using Firebase Authentication. However, I keep encountering the following error when trying to sign in with an email link: `Firebase: Error (auth/arugment-error)`.

I have been following this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth).

I have verified that the email link is valid, and the `isSignInWithEmailLink(url)` function returns `true` before attempting to sign in. Despite this, I still receive the 'auth/argument-error' during the `signInWithEmailLink(email, url)` process.

I've reviewed the code and made sure that the email and URL arguments passed to the `signInWithEmailLink` method are correct and in the expected format.

This is the code I have currently.

```js
loginConfirm = (url: string): Promise<any> => {
    console.log(url);
    if (this.afAuth.isSignInWithEmailLink(url)) {
      console.log("isSignInWithEmailLink worked!");
      var email: string = window.localStorage.getItem('emailForSignIn');
      if (!email) {
        email = window.prompt("Please provide your email for confirmation");
      }
      console.log(email); // verify email is correct
      console.log(url); // make sure url is the same as earlier (sanity check)
      return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailLink(email, url)
      .then((result) => {
        window.localStorage.removeItem('emailForSignIn');
        console.log("we are signed in");
        return result;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error code:", error.code);
        console.log("Error message:", error.message);
        throw error;
      })
    }
    else {
      console.log("isSignInWithEmailLink did not work :/");
      return Promise.resolve();
    }
  }
```

The full error message is

```
core.mjs:7739 ERROR FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).
    at we (index-e3d5d3f4.js:499:40)
    at Me (index-e3d5d3f4.js:503:15)
    at R.credentialWithLink (index-e3d5d3f4.js:3861:9)
    at index-e3d5d3f4.js:5640:42
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at e (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at P (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:32:1
    at new t (zone.js:1429:21)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:21:1
```

Could someone help me understand the possible causes of this 'auth/argument-error' and suggest potential solutions to resolve it? I'm not sure what I might be missing or how to troubleshoot this further. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just fixed it! Let me know if I need to do anything else.

Comment: I seems that one of the parameters you pass to Firebase is not valid. Did you already set a breakpoint on `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailLink` and check the values of `email` and `url` when the error occurs?

Comment: I did check using `console.log`. The values all seem fine.

Comment: What did you do to fix it?

Comment: I actually haven't fixed it yet. Are you running into a similar issue?